# camel throttle properties not work

Tags: apache-camel, throttling

I use a throttle on my route like this:

```
  <throttle id="_throttle1" rejectExecution="true" timePeriodMillis="10000">
            <constant>1</constant>
            <bean beanType="com.company.Test"
                id="_bean1" method="test"/>
  </throttle>
```

I'm using org.apache.camel.spring.spi.BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigure in my route, that works.

I would like to make the timePeriodMillis parametric, for example:

```
 <throttle id="_throttle1" rejectExecution="true" timePeriodMillis="{{test}}">
            <constant>1</constant>
            <bean beanType="com.company.Test"
                id="_bean1" method="test"/>
  </throttle>
```

I have the following error:

```
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "{{test}}"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:578) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl._parseLong(DatatypeConverterImpl.java:133) ~[jaxb-impl-2.3.0.1.jar:2.3.0.1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$19.parse(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:759) ~[jaxb-impl-2.3.0.1.jar:2.3.0.1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$19.parse(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:757) ~[jaxb-impl-2.3.0.1.jar:2.3.0.1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.TransducedAccessor$CompositeTransducedAccessorImpl.parse(TransducedAccessor.java:245) ~[jaxb-impl-2.3.0.1.jar:2.3.0.1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StructureLoader.startElement(StructureLoader.java:212) ~[jaxb-impl-2.3.0.1.jar:2.3.0.1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:577) ~[jaxb-impl-2.3.0.1.jar:2.3.0.1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:556) ~[jaxb-impl-2.3.0.1.jar:2.3.0.1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor.startElement(InterningXmlVisitor.java:75) ~[jaxb-impl-2.3.0.1.jar:2.3.0.1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:168) ~[jaxb-impl-2.3.0.1.jar:2.3.0.1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:244) ~[jaxb-core-2.3.0.1.jar:2.3.0.1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:281) ~[jaxb-core-2.3.0.1.jar:2.3.0.1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:250) ~[jaxb-core-2.3.0.1.jar:2.3.0.1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:281) ~[jaxb-core-2.3.0.1.jar:2.3.0.1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:250) ~[jaxb-core-2.3.0.1.jar:2.3.0.1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.scan(DOMScanner.java:127) ~[jaxb-core-2.3.0.1.jar:2.3.0.1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.scan(DOMScanner.java:110) ~[jaxb-core-2.3.0.1.jar:2.3.0.1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.scan(DOMScanner.java:103) ~[jaxb-core-2.3.0.1.jar:2.3.0.1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.BinderImpl.associativeUnmarshal(BinderImpl.java:161) ~[jaxb-impl-2.3.0.1.jar:2.3.0.1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.BinderImpl.unmarshal(BinderImpl.java:132) ~[jaxb-impl-2.3.0.1.jar:2.3.0.1]
    at org.apache.camel.model.ModelHelper.loadRoutesDefinition(ModelHelper.java:171) ~[camel-core-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]
    at org.apache.camel.model.ModelHelper.loadRoutesDefinition(ModelHelper.java:152) ~[camel-core-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.loadRoutesDefinition(DefaultCamelContext.java:1036) ~[camel-core-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]
    at fr.erdf.ose.ile.routes.RouteManager.loadXMLRoutes(RouteManager.java:43) ~[RouteManager.class:na]
```

Could you help me?

Comment: do you use springboot ? or just spring ?  if so which version? can you show your pom

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Camel Throttle Docs](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/docs/eips/throttle-eip.adoc) you can at least make the **number of requests** dynamic. However, they don't mention the time span.

So instead of configuring 1 request during X millis, you can configure **X requests during a fixed number of millis**.

```
<throttle timePeriodMillis="1000">
    <!-- use a header to determine how many messages to throttle per sec -->
    <header>throttleValue</header>
    <to uri="..."/>
</throttle>
```

You could give it a try to use your **property placeholder instead of a message header**.

```
<constant>{{test}}</constant>
```

If that does not work you can still **set the message header in the route** using your property placeholder.

```
<setHeader headerName="throttleValue">
    <constant>{{test}}</constant>
</setHeader>
```

Answer (score 0):

See the Camel documentation about using property placeholders
http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html

The section *Using Property Placeholders for Any Kind of Attribute in the XML DSL*, eg you need to use the `prop:` with the `/placeholder` namespace to be able to specify the value as a placeholder.